# How to calculate components values for LM3421 in SEPIC mode

Tags: circuit-design, dc-dc-converter, led-driver, sepic

How can I calculate the components values for LM3421 in SEPIC mode?

In the [LM3421 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/lm3423), there is not much information about SEPIC topology. (Section 9.2.9.2 is labelled "Detailed Design Procedure", but contains nothing but a BOM.) Are the components selection equations similar to the buck-boost topology?

Answer (score 0):

I find it best to look for relevant app-notes if I'm doing something a little new to me! TI and Linear Tech have some good information on SEPIC and CUK converter design.
https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva168e/snva168e.pdf?ts=1652818467558

In general, the design equations for a SEPIC are about 1/2 similar to a buck-boost converter. It is designed almost as two cascaded switching converters where the first is a boost and the second is the inverse of a buck boost. The funkier topologies (SEPIC, CUK, etc) have funny effects on current and voltage ripple seen by the source and the load of the converter. Which can in some cases be extremely beneficial given the additional effort to design them. Here is a [link to a great video on SEPIC design](https://youtu.be/Alan-Z0ZlGM), and I would wager to guess that [THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m5OG_3-sbCs) video is the secret sauce missing from your datasheet ;)